# How to use Android Service from other project?

Tags: android, android-studio, service

I want to use an external project that is implemented as Android service. The service is used by adding it to the manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.my.ext.service"/>
```

But when I addthis line, I get the error:

```
Unresolved class 'TimerService' less... (⌘F1)
Validates resource references inside Android XML files.
```

And when I add the layout in my project:

```
<com.my.ext.service
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I get the error that

```
the class could not be found
```

I have imported the external service as an extra project into my Android Studio. How can I use the other project as a service for this project?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Your service class as XML layout.
You can use that service using

```
<service android:name="com.my.ext.service"/>
```

and execute that service from Main activity of your app using:

```
private Intent OtherService;
OtherService = new Intent((Context)this, (Class)YOURSERVICE.class);
MainActivity.this.startService(MainActivity.this.OtherService);
```